# Run Magento 2.4.6 from windows + PHP Storm

Tags: magento2

Im just checkout project from: https://github.com/magento/magento2
How to run directly Magento website from source code by PHP Storm?
Im using windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

For using the Magento the best option for you is to run on the Linux on Ubuntu
Then you can install the PHP Storm
magento 2.4.6 prerequisites are find with this link:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html?lang=en

Comment: There are many way to install magento like:
1. By using XAMPP and PHP standalone on windows
2. By using docker on windows
3. By wsl on windows

Im try all of above, but i need run magento from source code, not installed version.
Do you think like i mean?